# How do I specify a query string where the parameters are separated by + (pluses) in Swagger/OpenAPI?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, http, asp.net-web-api, query-string

I my ASP.NET Core Web API project, I'm trying to define a route where I can query a database of words to find words that are combination of a given array of letters. For example, for the input array `["d", "g", "o"]` I want to return words like `dog` or `good`.

Here's my controller with the desired GET method:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class CombinationsController : Controllerbase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] string[] letters)
    {
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

However, when I open this in Swagger and specify the desired query characters to be `"d"`, `"g"` and `"o"`, the resulting URL becomes `api/v1/combinations?letters=d&letters=g&letters=o` rather than a saner alternative such as `api/v1/combinations?letters=d+g+o`.

Is there a way to apply the saner alternative in ASP.NET Core when dealing with collections of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternatives are comma, space or pipe delimited as described in the documentation:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/

and

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/

I don't think there's a way within swagger to make the delimiters plusses.

You do, however, show comma delimiters.

Comma query parameters relies on style: simple (  the default as you have ) and explode: true.

[image]

I'm not sure there's a way to apply those settings just via attribute.

One of the extensions might allow that, but I've not come across it.

The attributes you use with swashbuckle work are used to generate json format objects to the open api standard.

You can extend the functionality using several interfaces.

IOperationFilter, IDocumentFilter etc.

What these do is allow you to fine tune what json you get from interpretation process.

eg

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-custom-parameters-in-swagger-using-asp-net-core-3-1/

https://blog.codingmilitia.com/2022/02/21/openapi-extensions-and-swashbuckle/

Comment: Commas are even better, actually, thanks! But how would I define the controller template in ASP.NET?

Comment: To clarify, if I for example change the method attribute to `HttpGet("{characters*}")` and remove the `[FromQuery]` attribute from the `characters` input array, then I get a routing template exception.

Comment: Apparently the default schema *should* be to use the simple and non-exploded style, so there's an issue with the .NET implementation. See [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46530). I'll just accept your answer since there's not much to be done about it.